# css selector for value change

Tags: html, css

I wonder if it is possible to apply a CSS style when one of my HTML displayed value changes. I'd like to apply a "shake" effect when the values are updated.

Is there a CSS selector for that, something like following ?

```css
.button:change {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

Comment: `animation` + `@keyframes`? You also can use `css-variables` for the values and simply change the variable definition.

Comment: How would a button's value change? What sort of element has the `.button` class? (Also, while this might be possible in just CSS, this definitely feels better suited to a combination of CSS/JS. Are you trying to avoid JS, or is that a valid answer?)

Comment: You can't do this with css alone but you could use some js like a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for the change and then apply a class to trigger the animation when the value changes

Comment: @ths "CSS" and "HTML" aren't code, so please don't format them as such. See [Should I use code blocks when mentioning framework names/technologies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360491/4284627) and [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538)

Comment: @DonaldDuck but what I did is actually replaced a live snippet with a code block not the contrary! Please check [this question's revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73984688/revisions) and locate my edit attempt in order to confirm what I've said. Also, the keywords, like `CSS`, `HTML` etc... should be, in my humble opinion, styled as a code in order to highlight them to get the reader's attention.

Comment: @ths Replacing the snipped with a code block was good, I have nothing against that. I'm only referring to formatting "`CSS`" and "`HTML`" as code. If you look at the Meta posts I linked to in my previous comment, the community agrees that code formatting shouldn't be used for emphasis. If you really think emphasis is needed, you can use **bold** or *italics* (although I would argue that emphasis isn't needed at all in this case since it's already clear from the tags that this question is about HTML and CSS).

Comment: @DonaldDuck that's very opiniated, anyone has his/her opinion when it comes to how to write or implement things. Anyway, I agree with you, we should stick with the community rules. Thanks for pointing this out though.

Comment: In fact, I hoped to get the researched effect only with css : I cannot inject javascript on my script (Home assistant page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. CSS pseudo-classes key off states.

For example, `:focus` applies while an element has the focus.

There are none which target elements which have just changed from one state to another, and "has different content" isn't a state that is supported.

You'll need to use a DOM event and JavaScript for this.